How to suppress 'process started with pid' message
When I start a node in my ros2 launch file, I get the following info message:
[INFO] [mynode]: process started with pid [779797]
although I have set my default log-level for the node to ERROR.
Where is this message coming from and how can I suppress it unless my node log-level is set to INFO?

Perhaps you can try to set the logging level from the root logger in the roslaunch file: logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR). When the logger specific for starting the rosnode is created, it should get the defaults from the root logger.

I tried this and yes it does suppress the messages. However I also set the log level of nodes started from my launch file to ERROR. And I don't see some expected error log messages any more from these nodes. I'm not sure what the above setLevel is doing but it is suppressing all messages. When I do setLevel(logging.INFO), then it is as before i.e. the 'process started with pid' are now there and the nodes at ERROR level are printing error messages. So it doesn't really make sense to me why this affects the log level of nodes that I explicitly set the log level for.

It's not fixing anything but what if you set it to logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)

The result is the same as when I did logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR) i.e. all messages are suppressed.

Will setting the logging level of each node manually after setting the "global" logging to error help?
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/99332/specify-log-level-on-ros2-node-in-launch-file

I am setting the logging level of each node in the launch using "--log-level". This works except when I set the "global" to error. I am not sure what you are suggesting.

Did you trieed to adjust RCUTILS_LOGGING_SEVERITY?
export RCUTILS_LOGGING_SEVERITY=ERROR


Yes, tried that and it didn't make a difference

This looks like it is coming from the logger of ExecuteProcess in ros2 launch. However, I can't seem to find any way to control the verbosity of this logger. Anyone know how?
